# version Issue with elastic search and jaeger

Tags: elasticsearch, jaeger

We are using Jaeger with ELK stack in Azure. Recently updated the Jaeger version to 1.52 and elastic search version to 8.11. After upgrade the Jaeger UI is not showing any services not even the Jaeger services.
But we can search  key word like "trace ID" etc  through global search in Jaeger UI , its show the correct result/traceability.

we extracted error from jaeger-query and found http request from jaeger-query to ES failing with 400, given below:

```
Error: {
    "caller": "app/http_handler.go:493",
    "error": "search services failed: elastic: Error 400 (Bad Request): all shards failed [type=search_phase_execution_exception]",
    "level": "error",
    "msg": "HTTP handler, Internal Server Error",
    "stacktrace": "github.com/jaegertracing/jaeger/cmd/query/app.(*APIHandler).handleError\n\tgithub.com/jaegertracing/jaeger/cmd/query/app/http_handler.go:493\ngithub.com/jaegertracing/jaeger/cmd/query/app.(*APIHandler).getServices\n\tgithub.com/jaegertracing/jaeger/cmd/query/app/http_handler.go:164\nnet/http.HandlerFunc.ServeHTTP\n\tnet/http/server.go:2136\ngithub.com/jaegertracing/jaeger/cmd/query/app.(*APIHandler).handleFunc.traceResponseHandler.func2\n\tgithub.com/jaegertracing/jaeger/cmd/query/app/http_handler.go:537\nnet/http.HandlerFunc.ServeHTTP\n\tnet/http/server.go:2136\ngithub.com/jaegertracing/jaeger/cmd/query/app.(*APIHandler).handleFunc.WithRouteTag.func3\n\tgo.opentelemetry.io/contrib/instrumentation/net/http/otelhttp@v0.46.1/handler.go:285\nnet/http.HandlerFunc.ServeHTTP\n\tnet/http/server.go:2136\ngo.opentelemetry.io/contrib/instrumentation/net/http/otelhttp.(*middleware).serveHTTP\n\tgo.opentelemetry.io/contrib/instrumentation/net/http/otelhttp@v0.46.1/handler.go:229\ngo.opentelemetry.io/contrib/instrumentation/net/http/otelhttp.NewMiddleware.func1.1\n\tgo.opentelemetry.io/contrib/instrumentation/net/http/otelhttp@v0.46.1/handler.go:81\nnet/http.HandlerFunc.ServeHTTP\n\tnet/http/server.go:2136\nnet/http.HandlerFunc.ServeHTTP\n\tnet/http/server.go:2136\ngithub.com/gorilla/mux.(*Router).ServeHTTP\n\tgithub.com/gorilla/mux@v1.8.1/mux.go:212\ngithub.com/jaegertracing/jaeger/cmd/query/app.createHTTPServer.additionalHeadersHandler.func4\n\tgithub.com/jaegertracing/jaeger/cmd/query/app/additional_headers_handler.go:28\nnet/http.HandlerFunc.ServeHTTP\n\tnet/http/server.go:2136\ngithub.com/jaegertracing/jaeger/cmd/query/app.createHTTPServer.CompressHandler.CompressHandlerLevel.func6\n\tgithub.com/gorilla/handlers@v1.5.1/compress.go:141\nnet/http.HandlerFunc.ServeHTTP\n\tnet/http/server.go:2136\ngithub.com/gorilla/handlers.recoveryHandler.ServeHTTP\n\tgithub.com/gorilla/handlers@v1.5.1/recovery.go:78\nnet/http.serverHandler.ServeHTTP\n\tnet/http/server.go:2938\nnet/http.(*conn).serve\n\tnet/http/server.go:2009",
    "ts": 1709657320.93561 }
```

Please provide the your suggestion to resolve this issue.

Comment: Can anyone suggest how to debug this issue, where can I see http request between jaeger-query and elastic search.

Comment: I would recommend upgrading to the latest version of Jaeger which logs a more detailed error message from Elasticsearch that could point to the issue you have. `all shards failed` is a non-specific error message.